# C++: Rename all files in a directory

Tags: c++, file, directory, dirent.h

List of whats been achieved and what I'm stuck on to help with understanding what I am asking

*What I have achieved:*

Open a user specified directory, display all files within this directory.

*What I haven't yet achieved:*

Rename all files within this directory automatically according to a predefined name - Files are currently named as random characters, I wish to automatically rename them to "August 1", "August 2", "August 3" etc. Files have different extensions though, and I wish the extensions to remain the same.

So this is how I am opening and displaying the directory:

```
void DirectorySelector::OpenDirectory(void)
{
    // convert directory string to const char
    DIRECTORY = directory.c_str();

    pdir = opendir (DIRECTORY);
}

void DirectorySelector::DisplayDirectory(void)
{
    // read directory
    while (pent = readdir (pdir))
    {
        std::cout << pent->d_name << "\n";
    }
}
```

And this is what I am stuck on, renaming the files (files have different extensions, not sure if this will cause problems later on?)

I get the following error as soon as the program hits the while loop:

Unhandled exception at 0x009657C1 in MultipleRename.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCCCCCDE0.

```
void DirectoryOperator::StandardRename(void)
{   
    i = 1;

    while (pent = readdir (pdir))
    {
        oldname = pent->d_name;
        newname = "August " + i;

        OLDNAME = oldname.c_str();
        NEWNAME = newname.c_str();

        rename(OLDNAME, NEWNAME);
        i++;
    }   
}
```

Note: All declarations handled elsewhere and have removed validation for simplicity, if you need the code I can post it. 
Also I have already checked that the directory is still open in the DirectoryOperator class and I am using MSVS2012 on Windows.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _"Rename all files within this directory automatically according to a predefined name"_ What are your exact conditions/requirements about this point?

Comment: the files are currently named random characters, and I wish to rename them to "August 1", "August 2", "August 3", etc. Sorry for not making this clear in the text, thought the code explained it better than I could

Comment: But you want to keep the actual file extension, if I understood you correctly? You should edit your question, to point out the actual problems you have with your code.

Comment: BTW for working with paths, file names, extensions a.s.o., you might find the [boost::filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) classes useful.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ have edited question and looking into boost::filesystem, thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem with the line:

```
newname = "August " + i;
```

"August "  is a char* and i is added to the pointer before it is converted into a std::string.

So, when i==1, your string will be "ugust ", and when it is 2, it will be "gust ". Very quickly, when i > 8, you will run into undefined behavior.

Solutions:

```
newname = "August " + std::to_string(i); // c++11
```

or

```
#include<sstream>  
...
stringstream ss;
ss << "August " << i;
newname = ss.str();
```

Answer (score 1):

> *"I get the following error as soon as the program hits the while loop:"*
>
> `Unhandled exception at 0x009657C1 in MultipleRename.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCCCCCDE0.`

Most probably `pdir` isn't correctly initialized when the code

```
while (pent = readdir (pdir))
```

is called. The value `0xC0000005` indicates you're trying to dereference a `nullptr` somewhere.

Are you sure, that

```
pdir = opendir (DIRECTORY);
```

was called in sequence as intended, and the result was valid (`pdir != nullptr`)?

Comment: yes you're right, somewhere between the DirectorySelector and the DirectoryOperator classes pdir appears to have gone wrong